# No se puede abrir fichero generado con PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

¿Por qué al descargar mi archivo como Excel desde una página PHP me da un error de que no se puede abrir o la extensión no es válida? ¿Tendrá que ver esta parte del código donde le doy nombre y extensión?

```
<?php 
function activeErrorReporting()
{
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
}

function noCli()
{
  if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');
}

function getHeaders()
{
  // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

  // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
  header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
  header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
  header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que remover las comillas del nombre de archivo, puedes intentar con los siguientes headers, aunque si el archivo está mal formado de igual forma te enviará error al abrirlo.

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=01simple.xls");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

Habría que revisar el archivo con un editor de texto para corroborar que PHP no está generando ningún tipo de Output como errores o similares dentro del archivo.